# Magento admin dashboard is not showing after login to admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-enterprise, admin-panel, dashboard, admin-login

I have installed fresh Magento2.1 EE version.

After login to my admin panel, the dashboard shows the error

I have also attached the screenshot of the same

```
This site can’t be reached

There's the screenshot below that shows error in chrome.
```

[image]

Comment: Please try it in with new browser and clear cache

Comment: No Luck..Now i have tried with firefox browser..Still getting same issue.
"The connection was reset" Message with blank page.

Comment: Open the log file from var/log directory and post the log which is there in the log file

Comment: From Debug Log file:
main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://localhost/magentoe2/setup/index.php/session/prolong","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: Just restart your wamp server and try again - it still not work go to `app/bootstrap.php` file  and uncomment this line `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` by removing  then it will shows the errors to you

Comment: @ Manthan Sorry i have restarted wamp server and also tried with
ini_set('display_errors', 1);..But still Not working and not displaying any error..Simple it is showing blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Check `.htaccess` is available in your Magento root folder. If it's not there then just add the `.htaccess` file in root folder.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: @user3374995 Please let me know. Is this working for you or not.?

Comment: .htaccess file is already there in root folder.